# Videocalling in Ubuntu

Tags: skype

I want to make video calls in Ubuntu. Facebook doesn't seem to work, so I thought I'd download and install skype from its page. Is there any risk? Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to install skype or whether it has any risks? No more risk than downloading it for Windows or OSX. Why would there be? There are quite a [few risks involved](http://freedom-blog.net/2009/03/ten-reasons-why-you-should-boycott-skype/) in using skype in the first place but nothing specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: I thought that,because it is closed source,it could harm the os or spy or anything like that.

Comment: It could, theoretically. The question is, how much do you trust Microsoft? My point is that it is no more dangerous to install non-OS software on Linux than it is to do so on OSX or Windows.

Comment: Thanks,and Facebook videocalling is impossible to do right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This risk is minimal and not really an issue.  If you want to know where your packets are going, I would advise Wireshark.

On a separate note, do not use Skype website to download as, I assume your using 14.04, your way to get this.  Instead add these lines in Terminal:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install Skype`
This will install the correct version for the current Kernel.

For Skype Ethics go here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeEthics.  To further read behind the risks.

Answer (score 3):

Skype is [Closed Source](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software) software and the Ubuntu community can't offer any guarantee on its hidden code, you should trust the Skype©/Microsoft© developing team to use it.
**NOTE**: **Skype shouldn't be used for safety purposes or for commercial relationships** because it has [backdoors and severe security flaws](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Skype_security&oldid=611872805#Eavesdropping_by_design).
I **suggest** to use a software from that list:

1. [Pidgin](https://pidgin.im/) (*compatible with Windows*);
2. [Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/) (*compatible with Windows*);
3. [Twinkle phone](http://www.twinklephone.com/);
4. [Empathy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Empathy).

The listed software is [Open Source](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) and supported.

Comment under here for any question and don't forget to press the left UP arrow if I'm of any help.
Have a nice experience with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks,and Facebook videocalling is impossible to do right now?

Comment: Facebook© videocalling is the result of Skype + Facebook partership and needs proprietary software to function. For now you should use the Facebook video chat with the browser (if possibile), because the local Ubuntu software only support the XML-based protocols.
Remember that you can share on the text chat the chat addresses and then make a videochat with ekiga/empathy.